# What are "goat-demons"?

Tags: leviticus

In Leviticus 17:7 (NASB)

> And they shall no longer offer their sacrifices to the **goat demons** with which they play the prostitute. This shall be a permanent statute to them throughout their generations.”’

What are "goat-demons"?

Comment: Wikipedia: "The se'irim are also mentioned once in Leviticus 17:7 probably a recalling of Assyrian demons in shape of goats. Samuel Bochart and other Biblical scholars identified the Se'irim with Egyptian goat-deities. Leviticus 17:7 admonishes Israel to keep from sacrificing to the Se'irim."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Jewish Encyclopedia provides a wealth of information about demonology in the Tanach. I quote just a bit below, but provide the link to the full article:

> ...**The demons mentioned in the Bible are of two classes, the "se'irim"
> and the "shedim." The se'irim ("hairy beings"), to which the
> Israelites sacrificed in the open fields (Lev. xvii. 7; A. V.
> "devils"; R. V., incorrectly, "he-goats"), are satyr-like demons,
> described as dancing in the wilderness (Isa. xiii. 21, xxxiv. 14;
> compare Maimonides, "Moreh," iii. 46; Vergil's "Eclogues," v. 73,
> "saltantes satyri"), and are identical with the jinn of the Arabian
> woods and deserts (see Wellhausen, l.c., and Smith, l.c.). To the same
> class belongs Azazel, the goat-like demon of the wilderness (Lev. xvi.
> 10 et seq.), probably the chief of the se'irim, and Lilith (Isa.
> xxxiv. 14).** Possibly "the roes and hinds of the field," by which
> Shulamit conjures the daughters of Jerusalem to bring her back to her
> lover (Cant. ii. 7, iii. 5), are faunlike spirits similar to the
> se'irim, though of a harmless nature. The  (Job v. 23. A. V. "stones
> of the field"), with which the righteous are said to be in
> league—obviously identical with, if not a corruption of, the  (Mishnah
> Kil. viii. 5), explained in Yer. Kil. 31c as  "a fabulous mountain-man
> drawing nourishment from the ground" (see Jastrow, "Dict.," and Levy,
> "Neuhebr. Wörterb." s.v. )—seem to be field-demons of the same nature.
> The wilderness as the home of demons was regarded as the place whence
> such diseases as leprosy issued, and in cases of leprosy one of the
> birds set apart to be offered as an expiatory sacrifice was released
> that it might carry the disease back to the desert (Lev. xiv. 7, 52;
> compare a similar rite in Sayce, "Hibbert Lectures," 1887, p. 461, and
> "Zeit. für Assyr." 1902, p. 149).
>
> The Israelites also offered sacrifices to the shedim (Deut. xxxii. 17;
> Ps. cvi. 37). The name  (believed by Hoffmann, "Hiob," 1891, to occur
> in Job v. 21), for a long time erroneously connected with "the
> Almighty" (), denotes a storm-demon (from , Isa. xiii. 6; A. V.
> "destruction"; compare Psxci. 6, , "that stormeth about"; A. V. "that
> wasteth"). In Chaldean mythology the seven evil deities were known as
> "shedim," storm-demons, represented in ox-like form; and because these
> oxcolossi representing evil demons were, by a peculiar law of
> contrast, used also as protective genii of royal palaces and the like,
> the name "shed" assumed also the meaning of a propitious genius in
> Babylonian magic literature (see Delitzsch, "Assyrisches Handwörterb."
> pp. 60, 253, 261, 646; Jensen, "Assyr.-Babyl. Mythen und Epen," 1900,
> p. 453; Sayce, l.c. pp. 441, 450, 463; Lenormant, l.c. pp. 48-51). It
> was from Chaldea that the name "shedim" = evil demons came to the
> Israelites, and so the sacred writers in tentionally applied the word
> in a dyslogistic sense to the Canaanite deities 'in the two passages
> quoted. But they also spoke of "the destroyer" () Ex. xii. 23) as a
> demon whose malignant effect upon the houses of the Israelites was to
> be warded off by the blood of the paschal sacrifice sprinkled upon the
> lintel and the door-post (a corresponding pagan talisman is mentioned
> in Isa. lvii. 8). In II Sam. xxiv; 16 and II Chron. xxi. 15 the
> pestilence-dealing demon is called = "the destroying angel" (compare
> "the angel of the Lord" in II Kings xix. 35; Isa. xxxvii. 36),
> because, although they are demons, these "evil messengers" (Ps.
> lxxviii. 49; A. V. "evil angels") do only the bidding of God, their
> Master; they are the agents of His divine wrath....

https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/5085-demonology#anchor2

Answer (score 2):

It was a common form of worship at that time in that general area.

Ellicott's Commentary for English Readers

> (7) And they shall no more offer their sacrifices unto devils.--The word (s?irim) here translated "devils," literally denotes hairy or shaggy goats, and then goat-like deities, or demons. The Egyptians, and other nations of antiquity, **worshipped goats as gods**. Not only was there a celebrated temple in Thmuis, the capital of the Mendesian Nomos in Lower Egypt, dedicated to the goat-image **Pan**, whom they called Mendes, and worshipped as the oracle, and as the fertilising principle in nature, but they erected statues of him everywhere. Hence the **Pan**, Silenus, satyrs, fauns, and the woodland gods among the Greeks and Romans; and hence, too, the goat-like form of the devil, with a tail, horns, and cloven feet, which obtain in medieval Christianity, and which may still be seen in some European cities. The terror which the devil, appearing in this Pan-like form, created among those who were thought to have seen him, has given rise to our expression **panic**. This is the form of idolatrous worship which the Jews brought with them from Egypt, and to which reference is continually made.